# Session data not displaying

Tags: php

I have a page that checks for that the $_POST is set and then saves the post data to a session variable $_SESSION. When the page redirects it does not show the session data on the result page. When I do print_r($_SESSION) it shows an empty array. On each page I include a filed called include.php. In that page I do the following

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 

 include 'assets/include.php';
 require 'assets/dbinfo.php';

 $query = "SELECT * FROM Authors ORDER BY first_name";
 $resultObj = $connection->query($query);

 if(count($_POST))
 {
   $_SESSION['formPostData'] = $_POST;
   header('Location: final.php');
 }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Fundamentals</title>
        <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Header">
            <img src="assets/Dickens_Gurney_head.jpg" border="0" alt="">
            <h2>
                Join Our Literature Mailing List
            </h2>
        </div>        
        <div id="Body">
            <form method="post" action="index.php" >
                <div>
                    <label>Favorite Author:</label>
                    <select name="author">
                        <?php while($row = $resultObj->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                            <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['first_name']?> <?=$row['last_name']?></option>
                        <?php endWhile; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>      
                <div class="multiple">
                    <label>Favorite Century:</label>
                    17th Century <input type="checkbox" name="century[]" value="17th">
                    18th Century <input type="checkbox" name="century[]" value="18th"> 
                    19th Century <input type="checkbox" name="century[]" value="19th"> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Comments:</label>
                    <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>E-mail Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" />
                </div>
                <div  class="multiple">
                    <label>Receive Newsletter:</label>
                    Yes <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="yes">
                    No <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="no">
                </div>
                <div class="multiple">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Join Mailing List">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

final.php

```
<?php

include 'assets/include.php';

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";

$postedData = $_SESSION['formPostData'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Fundamentals</title>
        <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Header">
            <img src="assets/Dickens_Gurney_head.jpg" border="0" alt="">
            <h2>
                Mailing List Information
            </h2>
        </div>        
        <div id="Body">
            <div>
                <label>Favorite Author:</label> 
                <span><?=$postedData['author']?>&nbsp; </span>
            </div>      
            <div>
                <label>Favorite Century:</label>
                <span><?=$postedData['century']?>&nbsp; </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Comments:</label>
                <span><?=$postedData['comments']?>&nbsp; </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <span><?=$postedData['name']?>&nbsp; </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>E-mail Address:</label>
                <span><?=$postedData['email']?>&nbsp; </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Receive Newsletter:</label>
                <span><?=$postedData['newsletter']?>&nbsp; </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would change `include 'assets/include.php'` to `require_once  'assets/include.php'`  You probably have a bunch of Notice level errors for that...  / calling session start multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your form posts directly to `final.php`, so you should be able to access the posted data in `$_POST`.

It won't be set to the session because the code in `index.php` isn't run (the form posts to the other file)

If you want to set the data into the session, you should do so in `final.php`.

Comment: I no longer include session_start(); in index.php but the final.php still shows empty array. Array
(
    [formPostData] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: You should be getting the post data out of `$_POST` like so: `$postedData = $_POST`

Comment: Thank you atymic. I updated my code in the question to reflect the working copy.

Answer (score 0):

As per your form action which is in index.php , your form is posting to final.php where you are not setting any session data hence your session data is empty array.

If you want your session data to be print in final.php so you have to change the form action to index.php after setting session data you need redirect to final.php
Then you will get the session data.

Comment: Do I set the session data in final.php or index.php in order to print in final.php?

Comment: You need to set the session in final.php